# Merge excel files with multiple rows of headers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple excel files as follows (you may download test data from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4ss0zrd8hu77hw/test_data.rar?dl=0)) which have 3 row as headers in which `feature_row` are unique which could be used as column names of dataframes.

I need to merge them based on `date` and keeping multiple headers.

df1:

```
        country           jp           jp
0  feature_name      stock_a      stock_b
1   update_date   2021-09-15   2021-09-15
2      2006-6-2     100.0000     100.0000
3      2006-6-9      99.7800     100.2300
4     2006-6-16      97.7100      99.6300
5     2006-6-23      98.1100      98.4900
6     2006-6-30      97.5800      98.5700
```

df2:

```
        country           us           us
0  feature_name     cpi_food     core_cpi
1   update_date   2021-09-24   2021-09-24
2    1999-12-30   1,000.0000   1,000.0000
3      2000-1-4   1,025.7899   1,020.5759
4      2000-1-5   1,032.8712   1,024.9281
5      2000-1-6   1,073.6569   1,050.7501
6      2000-1-7   1,113.7831   1,081.9492
7     2000-1-10   1,135.3109   1,102.0936
8     2000-1-11   1,102.9618   1,037.0133
```

df3:

```
        country           cn           cn
0  feature_name    iCPI_food    iCPI_rent
1   update_date   2021-09-27   2021-09-27
2      2016-1-1      99.9712      99.9000
3      2016-1-2      99.9295      99.7684
4      2016-1-3     100.0744     100.1282
5      2016-1-4      99.8702      99.5830
6      2016-1-5      99.9254      99.8024
```

I'm able to loop excel files and merge them to one with code below, but the first and the third row of headers are missed.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

dfs = pd.DataFrame()

for file in glob.glob('./*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=[0, 2])
    df = df.rename(columns={'country': 'date'})
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').astype(str)
    df = df.sort_values(by='date')
    print(df)
    if dfs.empty:
        dfs = df.copy()
    else:
        dfs = dfs.merge(df, on='date', how='outer')
    dfs = dfs.sort_values(by='date')
    dfs.to_excel('./data.xlsx')
```

How could I get an expected excel file like this one:

[image]

**Updated result** with the updated code of @jezrael:

[image]

Comment: I haven’t used pandas yet, but I think your first and third row headers are missed due to the line containing the `pd.read_excel()` method. Specifically the `skiprows=[0, 2]` parameter.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to merge them without skip these rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid remove `MultiIndex`, convert first column to `DatetimeIndex` and append to list of DataFrames, for join use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) by `DatetimeIndex` with default outer join:

```
dfs, cols = [], []
for file in glob.glob('./*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(file)

    first = df.columns[0]
    df = df.set_index(first)
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
    df = df.sort_index()
    dfs.append(df)
    cols.extend(df.columns)

df_fin = pd.concat(dfs).reindex(cols, axis=1).reset_index()
df_fin.to_excel('./data.xlsx', merge_cells=False)
```

Another option:

```
dfs = []
for file in glob.glob('./*.xlsx'):
    print(file)
    df = pd.read_excel(file, header=[0, 1, 2], skipfooter=2)

    first = df.columns[0]
    df = df.set_index(first)
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d').astype(str)
    df = df.sort_index()
    dfs.append(df)

df_fin = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index()
df_fin = df_fin.dropna(how='all').sort_values(df_fin.columns[0])
df_fin.to_excel('./data.xlsx')
```

Comment: I updated the test data, pls check.

Comment: I test it raises an error: `ValueError: time data feature_name doesn't match format specified`.

Comment: @ahbon - Removed `, format='%Y-%m-%d'`, maybe in real file are not data in format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Or maybe there are already datetimes, then `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` should be removed.

Comment: I think it happens because in `df.index`, it also contains `'feature_name'` and  `'update_date'` which are not datetime.

Comment: @ahbon - yes, I change `pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=[0, 2])` to `pd.read_excel(file)`, then is not `MultiIndex in columns` ?

Comment: It seems not work out with your code either, do you mind test it?

Comment: @ahbon - if use `pd.read_excel(file,header=[0,1,2])` it working?

Comment: Yes, we are close the expected one.

Comment: @ahbon - Problem is sorting `MultiIndex` ?

Comment: Yes, another issue is one value takes two cells for country row.

Comment: @ahbon - answer was edited.

Comment: @ahbon - first column in files is not column with datetimes? Or only for some files?

Comment: Thanks but I still got some problems, pls test with data if you have some time. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('data1.xlsx',header=[0,1,2])
df2 = pd.read_excel('data2.xlsx',header=[0,1,2])
df3 = pd.read_excel('data3.xlsx',header=[0,1,2])    
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],ignore_index = True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to loop and read_excel files?